# Create Statement Returning ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURNING"

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I want to create a database table with a CREATE statement. I get an error Saying

```
Error: syntax error at or near "RETURNING".
```

I understand there is some sort of bug with the JDBC driver. As I found this.
[Postgres JDBC driver: PSQLException: syntax error at or near RETURNING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636120/postgres-jdbc-driver-psqlexception-syntax-error-at-or-near-returning)

It seems that I need to set Quirk Mode. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Right Now I have

```
Connection dbConnection;
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString,username,password);
Statement st = dbConnection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
st.executeUpdate(query,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

I dont know where I am supposed to set quirk mode

EDIT:

I'm sorry for missing details. It took me through the guided way.

The statement is made through

```
st.executeUpdate(query,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

And the SQL is

```
        String employeeTable="CREATE TABLE \"employee\" (\n" + 
                "   \"employee_id\" serial,\n" + 
                "   \"employee_first_name\" TEXT,\n" + 
                "   \"employee_middle_name\" TEXT,\n" + 
                "   \"employee_last_name\" TEXT,\n" + 
                "   \"employee_dob\" date ,\n" + 
                "   \"employee_ssn\" TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',\n" + 
                "   \"employee_wages\" FLOAT(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',\n" + 
                "   \"employee_password\" TEXT DEFAULT '0',\n" + 
                "   \"employee_issupervisoer\" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',\n" + 
                "   \"employee_hassupervisoer\" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',\n" + 
                "   \"employee_supervisor_id\" integer,\n" + 
                "   \"employee_clockstatus\" BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false',\n"+      // True = IN : False = OUT
                "   \"employee_lastpunch\" timestamp, \n"+
                "   \"employee_isactive\" BOOLEAN, \n"+
                "   CONSTRAINT employee_pk PRIMARY KEY (\"employee_id\")\n" + 
                ") WITH (\n" + 
                "  OIDS=FALSE\n" + 
                ");\n";
```

Honestly I don't think that SQL matters though. This statement worked for me about 6 months back. I dont know what changed but I changed from Postgresql 9.4 to 10.7? whatever the most recent 10.x stable is. and I updated my Gradle to

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql
compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.6'
```

Comment: And the query is?

Comment: *"CREATE query"* If the SQL *statement* is a `CREATE` statement, then it is not a *query*. A `SELECT` statement is a SQL *Query*. All other SQL statements are not that: *Statements*. So don't call `executeQuery` unless it's a `SELECT` statement. Use `executeUpdate` instead. --- As for the syntax error, how did you envision us helping with that, when we can't see the statement being executed?

Comment: There is no syntax error. As I stated it is a simple Create _statement_. If you read get an Idea of what the problem was for the link that I posted, It should give you some greater insight. As I am not as articulate I thought it would be a good Idea to give a much more defined problem as an example

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but did you read the other article? There is a driver problem that I do not know how to solve. the Driver is blindly tacking on a "RETURNING" at the end of my SQL statement. Its not my code per se, But there is a work around to this bug.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need all those embedded double quotes around the identifiers. You can remove them and make your Java code more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not combine a `CREATE TABLE` statement with a RETURNING clause (as it does not "return" anything).

When you call `executeUpdate(query,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)` you are requesting the generated keys from a DML statement to be returned. The Postgres JDBC driver does this by adding a `RETURNING` clause to the query - which obviously makes no sense with a DDL statement.

Use `execute(query)` instead.

Or `executeUpdate(query)` (without requesting generated keys)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read the question and the supporting link's and formulate a response that answers my question and fixes my problem. I wish I could up vote you like 10 more times

Comment: Technically a driver should support it and handle it as a normal statement. From the [apidoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-int-): _"The driver will ignore the flag if the SQL statement is not an INSERT statement, or an SQL statement able to return auto-generated keys (the list of such statements is vendor-specific)."_ So while you normally wouldn't execute a create table statement this way, the driver should handle it correctly.

Comment: I noticed this was fixed somewhere between driver versions 42.2.9 and 42.7.1